# Running Open Vas via KALI Linux

Tags: centos, kali-linux

We would like to run open-vas penentration test on a remote server and would no like to install it on the remote machine. Thus we have setup a Kali Linux Live machine for this purpose. So we first went into open-vas setup and towards the end we capture as below.

```
sent 1953267 bytes  received 3317820 bytes  71715.47 bytes/sec
total size is 159182950  speedup is 30.20
[i] Checking dir: ok
[i] Checking MD5 checksum: ok
Stopping OpenVAS Manager: openvasmd.
Stopping OpenVAS Scanner: openvassd.
All plugins loaded                                   
Starting OpenVAS Scanner: 
openvassd.
Starting OpenVAS Manager: openvasmd.
Restarting OpenVAS Administrator: openvasad.
Restarting Greenbone Security Assistant: gsad.
Enter password: 
ad   main:MESSAGE:30553:2002-01-01 00h34.24 UTC: No rules file provided, the new user will have no restrictions.
ad   main:MESSAGE:30553:2002-01-01 00h34.24 UTC: User admin has been successfully created.
```

Next went to setup openvas-gsd I try to login but then I read at the site it says this "Note: that the scan engine must have OMP support enabled for the given port for a successful connection? What should I do here?

Comment: How are you trying to connect?  Or do you know how to try to connect?

Answer (score 1):

If this is because you're trying to connect from a remote machine rather than from a process running on the server, you need a workaround.  At the command-prompt (it should be in your path logged in as root), type:

```
% openvasmd -a ip-of-this-server -f
```

This incantation will force the server to listen for remote connections without doing the "set public omp" that [Greenbone directs you to do at the "GSM command line"](http://www.greenbone.net/learningcenter/remote_controlled.html), which I've spent many hours trying to figure out how to find and use.  You will need to type this every time you reboot the machine (and of course you'll have to restart OpenVAS from the menu every time you reboot the machine as well, AFAIK).

Comment: @I prefer to run test from the web-gui. So each time how to start openvas ? Is it I need to go into the openvas-setup ?

Comment: Sorry for my slow response.  Yes, I always use openvas-setup.  I have tried to manually run OpenVAS on systems I installed it from scratch on, and it was always challenging.

Comment: I believe you can run openvas-setup from the command-line if you prefer.  It seems like I ended up deciding to devote a window to this for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if you're connecting from a client on the Kali Linux box (gsd from the Kali menu, or `https://localhost:9390` in the browser) it should just work ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0b4SVyP0IqI)).  Are you running Kali 1.0.4?  I know they suffered from a breakage in OpenVAS in 1.0.3, but I believe 1.0.4 just worked for me by first selecting "openvas setup" from the Kali menu and then "openvas start gsd"

Comment: @I am confuse now because I can start the open vas on localhost:9392 the problem is that I am receiving error of tls related. I have tried this solution from here too http://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?3109-Openvas-Greenbone-Web-Hangs&highlight=openvas . Another thing I ran uname -a its showing me Linux kali 3.7-trunk-686-pae. Any other information should I provide ?